# R/Shiny: View full stack/execution log

Tags: r, shiny

I'm debugging a Shiny web app, and would like to see the entire control flow/execution path over the course of rendering and updating the generated website.

Is there a way to capture/print/dump-to-file every line of code that is executed in the process of rendering/updating a Shiny app? It would also be good (maybe better?) to see every line of R code parsed by the running R interpreter instance; I'm not concerned about length of this output, and would prefer to get things as verbosely as possible.

I have looked into the [stack tracing Shiny functions](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.1/stacktrace.html) but these seem to be intended for error catching/handling/reporting. The app is not generating errors/warnings, just setting some variables to `NULL` at some point when they shouldn't be, so I'm not sure if this is the right approach. These stack tracing functions also seem to be more localized, designed to operate within a given reactive variable/function/render rather than following the control/execution flow across differing reactives/rendering functions in an app.

This app is a large, company-internal app so I cannot give a MRE/MWE.

Comment: Not sure full stack execution log exists in Shiny, but [here is a description of the possibilities](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the [`profvis` package](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/) that does more-or-less exactly what I want by taking a snapshot of the execution stack at a fixed time interval (default 10ms). I'm still working on using this tool to debug, but I believe this will get me there and would also be useful to others debugging Shiny apps that need more than `browser()` and/or `reactlog`.

Specifically, I have been doing:

```
#install.packages("profvis")
library(profvis)
exec_log <- profvis(runApp("myShinyApp"))
```

...interact with the `myShinyApp` web page enough to trigger the bug, then interrupt execution...

```
print(exec_log)
```